# Nautilus keep crashs on mounting samba drives

Tags: nautilus

I am unable to use network drives on ubuntu 12.10. I have 2 computers with windows xp and 7 all connected to a router.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that should be reported as a bug: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs